# magento-configurable-auto-pricing at backend

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, price

I want To set auto pricing configurable(Parent) Products At backend  Parent Price should be come lowest price  from simple(child)Products. except  $0 price product.
**Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to show the lowest price simple price on the front end:

https://github.com/organicinternet/magento-configurable-simple

You can then run a script to update configurable prices from lowest price simple with this:

```
<?php
require '/fullpath/httpdocs/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$collectionConfigurable = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'));
foreach ($collectionConfigurable as $_configurableproduct) {    
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_configurableproduct->getId());
$original_price = $product->getData('price');
$new_price = $product->getPrice();
if ($original_price != $new_price){
$product->setPrice($new_price);
$product->save();
echo "\n\n" . $product->getName() . ' updated price from: ' . $original_price . ' to: ' . $new_price;
}
}
?>
```

Done.

Comment: **@Mike Tim Turner** Thanks  for reply How can I run This script I am new in magento Thanks

Comment: Create a Cron to run this script. this will be done on your server outside of Magento. Or you can put the file path in your browser to run if you have the correct permissions

Comment: Yes i have permission I am running via Browser  But I am Gtting Error This  
Fatal error: Call to a member function getResourceModelInstance() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-1.9.2.4\app\Mage.php on line 491

Comment: First I create  file At Root Folder OF FTP by name **price_update** And 
And Include **include_once 'app/Mage.php';** And Past Your Script

Comment: I've updated it. Try now

Comment: Thanks It Worked But now Issue is Price are Not changing of Other Simple Products  at Front  End . I Mean A Product Price is Green XL = $15  And Green SM = $10. So Now XL Size Product Price Are Not changing.

Comment: Try re-indexing, other than that my script wouldn't have any impact on simple products and you should create a new question. Please Mark as answered. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54993/discussion-between-grace-and-mike-tim-turner).

Comment: This answers your original question. Mark as solved :/